# Executing a script file on oracle 12c

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g, oracle12c, sqlplus

I have the following subject.

I am new on Oracle 12c. I have a little experience working on 11g, and in this opportunity I need to migrate a whole database.

On 11g, through sqlplus, I do this:

```
sqlplus USER/PASSWORD @file.sql
```

I know on 12c we have containers. And on each one we have our users. I this case, I do not know how to execute the same file.sql inside a specific user (inside a specific container).

I was trying to do something like:

```
sqlplus CONTAINER USER/PASSWORD @file.sql
```

but it does not work.

Thank you for helping.

Comment: Please specify what you mean by "does not work"

Comment: Sounds like the question is really how to connect to a specific PDB, regardless of any tool or script.

Answer (score 0):

Well;

All what I have to do is:

```
sqlplus USER/PASSWORD@CONTAINER @file.sql
```

That's all.

Merci beaucoup!

Comment: I think the issue here is not so much containers or 11g vs. 12c, but that the operating system has a default environment variables set for one database but not another. Check your environment variables and look in startup or .profile files.